# Saving data on phone in a Cordova app

Tags: apache, cordova, local-storage, storage

I am making a mobile app using Cordova and I need to save some sensitive and not so sensitive data inside the phone. I am a bit lost on what is the best way to do it.

I need to save:

1. A JSON web-token (for authentication).
2. A response from server (I save this to populate my page in case the GET request fails).
3. Coordinates information when user is logging data to the app (for later upload to a server from with in the app). These will be many separate logs, and can be large in size for local storage ~5-10 MB.

Till now i have been successfully saving everything I need to the local storage but I don't think that is the correct way to do it. So that is why I need some help in deciding what is the best course to take from security point of view.

Saving server response is just for better UI experience and static in size so I guess local storage is a good option to use.
But web-tokens and GPS logs is sensitive information and I dont want to keep it in the local storage as it is accessible from outside the app.
What other options do I have?

[Cordova still doesn't have encrypted storage](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/security/index.html#encrypted-storage).

Is saving to `files` a good approach? This [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#page-toc-source) says that data contained inside `cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory` is private to the app.So can I use it to save the logs and the token?

The [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) also lists the file systems for Android and iOS and lists which of those are private.

I am currently working with android phones but want to extend the app to iOS later. I have never worked with file systems and caches before so I am a bit lost.

Comment: I think this is probably the right approach: https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage

Comment: Thanks @JosiahDaniels . I will try this out but it has a catch for android. **This means that any values saved using the plugin could be lost if the user changes security settings. The plugin should therefore be used as a secure credential cache and not persistent storage on Android**. Are there any other options? What about the options I asked about in the question